retrofit multipart form data in flutter web
when i am using my flutter project on desktop/mobile i can use File from 'dart:io' in my request like this
  @MultiPart()
  @POST("v1/images/upload")
  Future<UploadImageResponse> uploadImage(
    @Part(name: "file", contentType: "image/png") File imgFile,
    @Part(name: "sub_id") String uid,
    @Part(name: "breed_ids") String? breedId,
    @Part(name: "category_ids") int? categoryId,
  );

it works perfectly fine.
but when i am running on web, i can't create the normal File form 'dart:io', on web we have web file from 'dart:html', so how to send that web file in the uploadImage request, even though retrofit package takes only file from 'dart:io'?
if this is not working, could you please give me other solutions that I could use in my case?
i tried to make
  @POST("v1/images/upload")
  Future<UploadImageResponse> uploadWebImage(
    @Part(name: "file", contentType: "image/png") MultipartFile imgFile,
    @Part(name: "sub_id") String uid,
    @Part(name: "breed_ids") String? breedId,
    @Part(name: "category_ids") int? categoryId,
  );

but this gives me this issue when i am trying to generate retrofit code
[SEVERE] retrofit_generator on lib/data/network/app_api.dart:
Exception: toJson() method have to add to MultipartFile
also this is not working, gives me the same issue with code generation
import 'dart:html' as html;
  @POST("v1/images/upload")
  Future<UploadImageResponse> uploadWebImage(
    @Part(name: "file", ) html.File imgFile,
    @Part(name: "sub_id") String uid,
    @Part(name: "breed_ids") String? breedId,
    @Part(name: "category_ids") int? categoryId,
  );


